# Best option to refresh a single query using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workboook with 4-6 queries and I just would like to refresh 1 of the 6 with VBA. My question is, am I using the fastest option below?

And nope, I don't want to use the Refresh All / Refresh button within Excel, I needed to include this in a sub.

CODE:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Raw").OLEDBConnection.refresh

    ' THESE ALSO WORK
    ' ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ' Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

These don't work:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Raw").refresh
    ThisWorkbook.Connections("Raw").refresh
```

Thank you for the kind answers in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest should be to refresh that specific query by name.

```
ThisWorkbook.Connections("YourOLEDBconnection").OLEDBConnection.refresh
```

This would be a smaller call stack but not much/if any of a noticeable time difference. It also only concerns itself with the connection open, refresh, close pathway.

Something like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").ListObjects("query table name").QueryTable.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

I think would have a longer call stack making an additional call to the connection refresh shown at top. You may incur a small amount of overhead as well in relation to the table itself (any formatting that is re-painted etc).

You can time the various methods and look for the best median refresh time and take that method.

Comment: Is not that the same as going to the worksheet I need a refresh to, then running with a VBA code, Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False ?

Comment: ? I am saying that refreshing the table will in the background refresh the connection so just refresh the connection.

Comment: I mean is ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").ListObjects("query table name").QueryTable.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False  basically the same as Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False ?

Comment: No. The second incurs more i/o overhead as you must first touch the sheet and select the target.

Answer (score 0):

This also work, ("Queries" instead of "Connections"):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("YourQueryName").Refresh
```

But to check the best performance the code profiling should be performed.

Answer (score -1):

Connections has no exact name referred to query, this is the problem. I've solved it this way:

```
Sub refexample()
RefreshQuery "Query - Raw"
End Sub

Sub RefreshQuery(ByVal qry As String)
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim c As WorkbookConnection
  For Each c In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  Debug.Print c.Name & " " & c.ranges(1).Parent.Name
    If qry = c.ranges(1).Parent.Name Then
      c.OLEDBConnection.Refresh
    End If
  Next
 End Sub
```

Or if you renamed once all connections, you can use it directly:

```
Sub RenameQueries()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim c As WorkbookConnection
  For Each c In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  Debug.Print c.Name & " " & c.ranges(1).Parent.Name
    c.Name = c.ranges(1).Parent.Name & "Conn"
  Next
End Sub

Sub refexample()
  ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - RawConn").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
End Sub
```