# Import data from .XLSX file into .XLSM file

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-excel

I'm trying to import data from tab "Sheet1" from file (export.xlsx) from a map called "EXPORT DOCUMENTS" on my desktop into an (Excel VBA) xlsm file on a specific tab called "cleaned".

I'm using a recording of DATA > GET DATA > FROM FILE with the following code:

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\EXPORT DOCUMENTS\EXPORT.XLSX""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Vendor"", In" & _
        "t64.Type}, {""Reference"", type text}, {""Document Number"", Int64.Type}, {""Document Type"", type text}, {""Invoice Reference"", type text}, {""G/L Account"", Int64.Type}, {""Payment Method"", type text}, {""Payment terms"", Int64.Type}, {""Payment block"", type text}, {""Document Date"", type date}, {""Entry Date"", type date}, {""Posting Date"", type date}, {""Ne" & _
        "t Due Date"", type date}, {""Amount in Doc. Curr."", type number}, {""Document Currency"", type text}, {""Amount in Local Currency"", type number}, {""Text"", type text}, {""Document Header Text"", type text}, {""Assignment"", type text}, {""Clearing Date"", type date}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Sheet1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$B$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Sheet1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Sheet1").ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Sheet1").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Sheet1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium4"
    Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False
End Sub
```

When running the macro it works only once and if I want to do this repeatedly I need to rename the following part in the code:

`Name:="Sheet1"`

Any suggestions on how to avoid that? How can I import the same .xlsx data to the same tab in the .xlsm file repeatedly without renaming "Sheet1" in the code

Comment: Why do you need run the macro multiple times? You should be fine with updating the query whenever the data changes. Currently your code **adds** a query - as the name of queries have to be unique, that's why you get the error, when you run the code a second time.

Comment: Instead of adding a new query `Queries.Add` refresh the old one: [Best option to refresh a single query using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607879/best-option-to-refresh-a-single-query-using-vba)

Comment: @Ike I checked the macro with different data (closing and opening the workbooks) but the macro still requests to rename.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried replacing .Add with .Refresh at different positions but no luck. How would you change the above code?

Comment: Did you see the the question I linked? It is not about randomly replacing `.Add` with `.Refresh` You need to have 2 macros. One that adds the query and another that can refresh it.